# How to use an external jsp file as a overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to popup an external jsp page as a popup when i click on hyperlink. And also I have to submit this page after performing some field validation. It is possible while using iframe. But it takes time to load the page. 
For example I have one link **registerNow**, after click on this link I have to show registration page as a overlay. And then after performing some field validations I have to **submit** the page. At that time the **url** of the application should not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow the below link to achieve my requirement  http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/external.html

Answer (score 2):

Use any modal popup scripts.

You may consider any of this

**1)** jQuery UI dialog  ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ )

**2)** jqModal ( http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)

**2)** Fancybox
 and a lot more...

Comment: @Pravallika69 read the links in the answer and stop being lazy !